# Download word document from MySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I store word documents, and not I want show these documents on my web page in the form of a downloadable link. 
This is the code I have:

```
<tr><td>CV: &nbsp </td><td><?php echo strtoupper ($cv)  ?></td></tr>
```

all this does is output an entire page of symbols Like this:

```
�C�m���f_��
```

I store the files as LONGBLOB in the database field, but what does the output php need to look like and include in order to be downloadable and actually make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the path to file in database. That way the file is stored in the server. All you have to do is create a link to the path stored in database.

Comment: The idea was that someone would upload their cv, then everyone else on the site can click and download the cv immediately. saving the file path in the database isnt something the user would really want to be doing

Comment: The cv is uploaded to server, you just store the path to server in database.

Comment: Im using xampp though

Comment: Xampp is your server. One example: user upload cv that is stored in "/xampp/htdocs/site/documents/cv.pdf". Instead of store "cv.pdf" in the database as blob, why don't you store "documents/cv.pdf" as text. In the page that users can download cv, put a link "<a href='documents/cv.pdf'>Download</a>".
A big advantage is that this way your database is a lot smaller.

Comment: well in that case it makes just as much sense hard coding all the links to cv's in through the code and not bother with storing a text ink

Answer (score 0):

In your Question heading ***Download word document from MySQL database using php***

Simply thing is **you cant upload file to database**. Best practice is you have to **upload file path** only. so then you can get path to download.

***Example***

```
Path - upload/word/123.doc
```

so in view, you can just use

```
<a href="./upload/word/123.doc"  target="_blank"
```

Comment: I don't use MySQL and don't wish to sound pedantic but I would think if it supports BLOBs then you can save a file as a binary to a database.

Comment: The idea was that someone would upload their cv, then everyone else on the site can click and download the cv immediately. saving the file path in the database isnt something the user would really want to be doing

Comment: change code way you need. and you can show in user profile download option with link to user csv path

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PHP but a common strategy in this situation is that the hyperlink is a link to a new page. The link passes the id to this page for the database to get the blob.

Rather than return a webpage in the response we hijack it, writing the binary data into the response stream and change the  content-type header so the browser knows how to deal with the response.

This link might get you started? [How do I send files to the Browser?](http://crossedstreams.com/2008/10/12/how-do-i-send-a-pdf-doc-mp3-etc-file-to-the-browser/)